# Cannot refer to Kotlin generated setter using Class::property

Tags: java, kotlin, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use kotlin fixtures to create a builder object:

```
 package bla.testdoubles.stubs
 
 import bla.testdoubles.TreehouseTestFixture
 import bla.testdoubles.fakes.FakeRequest
 import bla.ServiceRequest
 
 typealias Builder = ServiceRequest.ServiceRequestBuilder<FakeRequest>
 
 val FakeRequestFixture = MyCustomTestFixture<FakeRequest> {
 }
 
 val ServiceRequestFixture = MyCustomTestFixture<Builder> {
     property<Builder, FakeRequest>(Builder::request) {
         FakeRequestFixture
     }
 
     property<Builder, String>("fullRequestURI") {
         // TODO: use Faker
         "123"
     }
 }
```

The compiler says that Builder::request is a private member and cannot be accessed. I'm trying to refer to the automatically generated setter and not the private request  variable that the Builder declared.

This is the error:
Cannot access 'request': it is private in 'ServiceRequestBuilder'
The generated setter uses the setRequest  method and that should be public.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? What is the "automatically generated setter"? What generated it?

Comment: Kotlin generates a property out of the `getRequest` and `setRequest` methods.

Comment: Okay, now post a [mcve].